# Retrofit call request only receiving message part, not body part

Tags: android, retrofit2

After some changes in my code, I am able to send a retrofit request to an API.

The problem now is that I am only receiving the message part from the response, not the body part.
This is the interface:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("token")
    Call <ResponseBody> createLoginRequest(@Field("username") String username,
                                          @Field("password") String password,
                                          @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
                                          @Field("latitude") String latitude,
                                          @Field("longitude") String longitude

                                          );
}
```

And this is the request part:

```
 private void login_Request() {


        Log.d("ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST", "ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST");

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);


        Call<ResponseBody> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createLoginRequest("HALEJANDRO", "ALEJANDR0123", "password", "19.4953148", "-99.1131595");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST", "ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST success "+response);




            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST", "ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST error");
            }
        });


    }
```

And this the received response:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://10.....:5000/token}
```

I would need to get the body part to further work with the received data.

EDIT

The response received using a rest api client, like postman, looks like as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get response body using `response.body()`.

Like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String object = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("response string.....", object);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply unmarshal the response?

```
public class MLoginResponse {

    @SerializedName(value="access_token")
    public String accessToken;

    @SerializedName(value="token_type")
    public String tokenType;

    @SerializedName(value="expires_in")
    public Long expiresIn;

    public String twoFactory;

    @SerializedName(value=".issued")
    public String issued;

    @SerializedName(value=".expires")
    public String expires;

}
```

Here what your request should look like:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("token")
Call<MLoginResponse> createLoginRequest(...);
```